# Why is SQLExecute returning SQL_NO_DATA when running a procedure with NOCOUNT ON?

Tags: c, t-sql, stored-procedures, odbc, unixodbc

I have the following procedure, which I don't want SQL to show affected row counts:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UP_STOREDPROC @field VARCHAR(15)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (field) VALUES (@field);
GO
```

And a C project using unixODBC/FreeTDS to execute this proc after a prepared statement (`SQLPrepare`).

After the preparation, when it executes the statement by calling `SQLExecute`, it always return `SQL_NO_DATA` (100).

But, from [ODBC documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713584(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If SQLExecute executes a **searched update, insert, or delete** statement
>   that does not affect any rows at the data source, the call to
>   SQLExecute returns SQL_NO_DATA.

So, it's not a searched insert. If the first line of the procedure is changed to `SET NOCOUNT OFF` then everything works fine.

What is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to add something like: `SELECT 1 as Result;` to the end of the procedure?

Comment: That approach probably have the same effect of keeping a `set nocount off` at the end. Anyway, it's a hack, I don't want to solve the problem that way =\. Btw, it's supposed to work without it!!

Comment: Then the problem is in the way you execute that stored procedure. There are two ways: with results and without results. You running it in a way, which expects results. Try different way to call this procedure.

Comment: What exactly defines that I'm expecting results?

Comment: I do not know which language you use to code your application. I just know from my experience with other languages that you can run a SQL statement and get some results from it, but you can just execute it without getting anything. If you want to use your SPs only for that application and you are too lazy to do a research on the language then you better go with a "hack"

Comment: ok, in this case it's specific to unixODBC using C language. I will change tags properly.

Comment: If you specify `SET NOCOUNT ON;` it is a flag to your environment to pay no attention to affected rows or other `print` statements from SP. So in that case `SQL_NO_DATA` is absolutely right to be shown. If you `SET NOCOUNT OFF;` it must show `n rows affected`

Comment: But..it's not an error! The procedure has been executed successfully, but the function returns a misleading status.